# Get length of array without using length

Tags: arrays, ruby

In a completely contrived problem on exercism.io, I'm tasked to come up with a way to get the length/size of an array without using any enumerable methods.

I originally simply had:

```
  arr = [1,3,4]
  ctr = 0
  while arr[ctr]
    ctr += 1
  end
  ctr
```

The problem is that I can have `arr = Array.new(5)`, which is `[nil, nil, nil, nil, nil]`.

I've found two ways:

```
ctr = 0
loop do
  element = arr.fetch(ctr) { 'outofbounds!' }
  break if element == 'outofbounds!'
  ctr += 1
end
ctr
```

I'd like to do it without using `Array#fetch` because index out of bounds is just likely looking at the known length (which again I'm trying to implement).

Another solution:

```
  ctr = 0
  copy = arr.dup
  while copy != []
    ctr += 1
    copy.pop
  end
  ctr
```

This feels slightly right but `==` on `Array` first checks length then checks `==` on each element.  I'm trying to implement length so stuck again.

Comment: What about `Array#each`?

Comment: What is `counter` in your second code?

Comment: @sawa thanks - I adjusted all the examples to use the same variables now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your first solution is close. The problem, of course, is that `nil` is a valid element of the list. So the easiest solution is to add a sentinel value at the end which is *never* going to be an element of the list.

I've used this idiom from time to time; you just make a brand new instance of the `Object` class and use it as a value. No other object will ever compare equal to it, and it can't possibly be an element of the list since it was just now made up.

```
arr = [1,3,4]
end_of_list = Object.new
copy = arr.dup
copy.push end_of_list
ctr = 0
while end_of_list != copy[ctr]
  ctr += 1
end
ctr
```

Comment: Great suggestion

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution that's deliberately really *out there* because this question is an exercise in not doing things using the core API:

```
def array_length(a)
  b = a.dup
  c = [ ]
  f = 0

  while (b != [ ])
    c.push('')
    b.pop
    f = 1
  end

  e = c.join("\x01").to_s.unpack('C*')

  while (e[0])
    f += e.pop
  end

  f
end
```